# get the last common array value in PHP dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

I have original array as given below

```
$orginal_arra = Array(
    [0] => 53_0.1,
    [1] => 53_0.3,
    [2] => 54_0.2,
    [3] => 54_0.1,    
    [4] => 54_0.1,
    [5] => 54_0.19,
    [6] => 56_0.19,
    [7] => 56_0.50
);
```

The above array can explode by "_" separating

```
foreach($orginal_arra as $part) {
    if($part){
        $arr_parts = explode("_",$part);
        $arr1[] = $arr_parts[0];
        $arr2[] = $arr_parts[1];
    }
}
```

The $arr1 result after sperating

```
Array (
    [0] => 53,
    [1] => 53,
    [2] => 54,
    [3] => 54,
    [4] => 54,
    [5] => 54,
    [6] => 56,
    [7] => 56
)
```

The $arr2 result after sperating

```
Array (
    [0] => 0.1,
    [1] => 0.3,
    [2] => 0.2,
    [3] => 0.1,
    [4] => 0.1,
    [5] => 0.19,
    [6] => 0.19,
    [7] => 0.50
)
```

I want to return the array by combining $arr1 and $arr2 as like

```
$array = Array(
    [0] => 53_0.3,
    [1] => 54_0.19,
    [2] => 56_0.50
);
```

Is there any way to get the result like above using PHP Arrays.

Comment: is it just me that finds this really unclear?

Comment: You have to iterate over one array and get values from it, then get value under the same key in second array.

Comment: People (and by people I mean me) generally appreciate if they don't have to manually quote the values of your testcase if they were to actually try to help by making a working solution.

Comment: No, it's good.  Clear to me.

Comment: @apokryfos agreed.  That certainly slowed me down on my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_values` on grouping the array into an associative array. Use `array_values` to convert the associative array into a simple array.

```
$orginal_arra = array(
    '53_0.1',
    '53_0.3',
    '54_0.2',
    '54_0.1',    
    '54_0.1',
    '54_0.19',
    '56_0.19',
    '56_0.50'
);

$result = array_values(array_reduce($orginal_arra, function($c,$v){
    $key = explode('_', $v);   //explode the value
    $c[$key[0]] = $v;          //Use the first element of the explode value as a key and just overide the value
    return $c;
}, array()));


echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 53_0.3
    [1] => 54_0.19
    [2] => 56_0.50
)
```

Comment: When you use `explode()` to "halve" a string please use `2` as the optional limit parameter for two reasons.  It reinforces the intent of the code to future readers AND it tells explode that it can stop after the first explosion.

Answer (score 1):

`strstr()` is the perfect temporary key generator.  Each recurring key will overwrite the previous value.  When the loop finishes, just reindex the result array with `array_values()`. Clean and simple.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4nHND))

```
$original_array = Array(
    '53_0.1',
    '53_0.3',
    '54_0.2',
    '54_0.1',    
    '54_0.1',
    '54_0.19',
    '56_0.19',
    '56_0.50'
);

foreach ($original_array as $v) {
    $result[strstr($v, "_", true)] = $v;
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '53_0.3',
  1 => '54_0.19',
  2 => '56_0.50',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to combine `$array1` and `$array2`:

```
    <?php

    $array1= array(
        "0" => 53,
        "1" => 53,
        "2" => 54,
        "3" => 54,
        "4" => 54,
        "5" => 54,
        "6" => 56,
        "7" => 56
    );

    $array2 = array (
        "0" => 0.1,
        "1" => 0.3,
        "2" => 0.2,
        "3" => 0.1,
        "4" => 0.1,
        "5" => 0.19,
        "6" => 0.19,
        "7" => 0.50
    );
    $array1 = array_reverse($array1, true);

    $array1 = array_unique($array1);
    foreach($array1 as $key=>$val){
        $array1[$key] = $val."_".number_format((float)$array2[$key], 2, '.', '');
    }
    print_r(array_reverse($array1));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 53_0.30,
    [1] => 54_0.19,
    [2] => 56_0.50
)
```

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily convoluted.